# Aliases in MySQL and do maths

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to workout the effectiveness of a user  to display in a report, i complied the following statement

```
SELECT COUNT(`call_id`) AS logged 
            FROM `tbl_calls`
            WHERE `user_id_attended_by` = 24
            AND YEAR(`date_ack_by_tech`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
            AND MONTH(`date_ack_by_tech`) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
            AND `fk_supplier_id` = 3
    UNION ALL 
        SELECT COUNT(call_id) AS ACK
            FROM `tbl_calls`
            WHERE YEAR(`date_logged`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
            AND MONTH(`date_logged`) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
            AND `repaired_by` = 24
            AND `fk_supplier_id` = 3
```

The output for the above motioned statement as follows,

[image]

I need to get the percentages of the two totals in the pictures to add it to a report to get the users performance, I tried to create a temp table and entering the data into it but could not get it working in xampp.

Comment: Are you really looking for Jan 2022?  Last month did you really want Dec 2021?  (Think about the math.)

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT logged,
       100*logged/(logged+ack) percent_logged,
       ack,
       100*ack/(logged+ack) percent_ack
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(`user_id_attended_by` = 24) AS logged,
           SUM(repaired_by` = 24) AS ack
    FROM `tbl_calls`
    WHERE YEAR(`date_ack_by_tech`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
      AND MONTH(`date_ack_by_tech`) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
      AND `fk_supplier_id` = 3
    ) subquery
```

?

Comment: thanks fro the reply Akina, but i need to divide logged with ack /logged * 100

Comment: Beware of January.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what the difference is between `date_ack_by_tech` and `date_logged`, but I assume you have a reason for using them. So, I have not tried to *smudge* your queries together. If there is no need to differentiate between these two dates, then Akina's method is preferable.

I would drop the use of MONTH() and YEAR() and instead use a date range. This will make these criteria [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), which may or may not be helpful in this case. But it also does away with your current January issue (Jan 2023 returns Dec 2022, whereas Feb 2023 returns Jan 2022 - 1 month or 13 months).

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(`call_id`) AS logged 
    FROM `tbl_calls`
    WHERE `date_ack_by_tech` BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 13 MONTH - INTERVAL (DAY(CURRENT_DATE) - 1) DAY
                                 AND CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 12 MONTH - INTERVAL (DAY(CURRENT_DATE) - 1) DAY - INTERVAL 1 SECOND
    AND `user_id_attended_by` = 24
    AND `fk_supplier_id` = 3
) AS logged, (
    SELECT COUNT(call_id) AS ack
    FROM `tbl_calls`
    WHERE `date_logged` BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 13 MONTH - INTERVAL (DAY(CURRENT_DATE) - 1) DAY
                            AND CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 12 MONTH - INTERVAL (DAY(CURRENT_DATE) - 1) DAY - INTERVAL 1 SECOND
    AND `repaired_by` = 24
    AND `fk_supplier_id` = 3
) AS ack,
(SELECT ROUND(100 * logged / (logged + ack), 2)) AS percent_logged,
(SELECT ROUND(100 * ack / (logged + ack), 2)) AS percent_ack;
```

If you want to continue using your MONTH() and YEAR() method, you should change the year criterion to:

```sql
YEAR(`date_ack_by_tech`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 13 MONTH)
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies, i am trying to compile a report on the effectiveness of a user by the amount off calls logged against the amount he or she acknowledge on my DB Calls logged. Hope this help in resolving my query.

Comment: If none of these answers is providing what you are looking for, please update your question with a more detailed explanation.

Comment: HI Nnichols, no this helped me a lot, thanks, I read your comment and though it would explain the question better, but thanks will do that.